# Issues copying local postgresql database data to remote heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Heroku app with a postgresql database I'm trying to pre-populate with data created on my localhost postgresql installation.

I've been following the instructions from Heroku detailed both here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export and here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#restoring-from-backup but keep running into an issue that seems rather cryptic to me.

First, I've created my local database dumb using this command:

```
PGPASSWORD=password pg_dump -o -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U dbUser db_name > db/db_name.dump
```

I then followed the instructions to upload my dump file to a Cloud App url and try to then restore the database with the following command:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE_NAME 'http://path/to/db_name.dump' --app app_name
```

The following output the prints with an error:
Retrieving... done

```
 !    An error occurred and your restore did not finish.
 !    Please run `heroku logs --ps pgbackups` for details.
```

When I look at the logs, I see this output below which is complaining about an integer, and then a "invalid path", but I can't make sense why. The URL to the dump file is correct and accessible.

Any insight into this problem is much appreciated!

```
2013-02-04T20:15:06+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Started:  Mon Feb 4 20:15:06 UTC 2013
2013-02-04T20:15:06+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Location: e9d564f0-a67f-4c32-bad5-60798786b87b:/tmp/VFJ5WDiAHr
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: psql: bin//psql-9.2.1-64bit
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pv: bin//pv-1.1.4-64bit
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:       SELECT count(*) = 0 as is_empty
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:       FROM pg_class INNER JOIN pg_roles ON relowner = pg_roles.oid
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:       WHERE rolname <> '\''postgres'\'''
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: bin/brie: line 145: [: 9.1: integer expression expected
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_restore: bin//pg_restore-9.1.6-64bit
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  Schema |             Name              | Type  |       Info        
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: --------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------------
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | abilities                     | table | 554
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | abilities                     | table | abilities_pkey
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | champions                     | table | 110
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | champions                     | table | champions_pkey
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | effects                       | table | 934
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | effects                       | table | effects_pkey
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | items                         | table | 191
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | items                         | table | items_pkey
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | masteries                     | table | 56
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | masteries                     | table | masteries_pkey
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | runes                         | table | 305
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | runes                         | table | runes_pkey
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | schema_migrations             | table | 26
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | schema_migrations             | table | 
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | spells                        | table | 15
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | spells                        | table | spells_pkey
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | abilities_pkey                | index | abilities
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | champions_pkey                | index | champions
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | effects_pkey                  | index | effects
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | index_champions_on_updated_at | index | champions
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | index_items_on_item_id        | index | items
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | index_items_on_updated_at     | index | items
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | index_masteries_on_updated_at | index | masteries
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | index_runes_on_updated_at     | index | runes
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | index_spells_on_updated_at    | index | spells
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | items_pkey                    | index | items
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | masteries_pkey                | index | masteries
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | runes_pkey                    | index | runes
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | spells_pkey                   | index | spells
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  public | unique_schema_migrations      | index | schema_migrations
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: (30 rows)
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: 
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: start
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress:    0B 
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: 
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: 0.0bytes
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: done
2013-02-04T20:15:07+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Invalid path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default cloudapp urls are 30x redirects, and unfortunately at the time of this answer, pgbackpus doesn't follow redirects. I should get around to fixing that sometime, but in the mean time, do a `curl -I` on your cloudapp url and find the real url, and use that.

The hint there is the "invalid path" in the logs at the bottom.

Also for what it's worth, if you have the backup locally already, and it's not so big, you can just use `pg_restore` from your machine on the remote pg database.

Comment: I'll take a look at using the curl option to figure this out. Thanks so much for the fast response!

Comment: Indeed, using `curl -I` to find the final URL was the correct solution. Thank you!